# How do I programmatically pinpoint some links based on many types of URL?

Tags: java, android

I'm currently writing a Webcomic Reader app, and so far I have been able to extract out the 'Next' and 'Previous' links from the comic websites, provided that when I parse them using JSoup, I can get a a[href] tag that is valid and contains the value for the 'Next' or 'Previous' Link.

An example will be http://www.explosm.net/comics/ , When I parse them using JSoup I can find the tag "< Previous", which contains the value of the previous link.

However, this only works on websites with valid tags, but on some websites, they do not display tags for their a[href] stuff, for example http://awkwardzombie.com/

So is there a method/technique where I can find the link I want, from these kind of websites without using tags?

Answer (score 1):

For awkwardzombie.com, look at the hyperlink image's `alt` attribute, which gives an indication:

```
<img src="images/aznavb4o.png" alt="Next Comic" width="40" height="40" border="0">
```

Comment: That would work, however the real previous link is this one,

<a href="index.php?page=0&comic=090213">


The one you pointed out is simply the pic of the previous button.. But still I would keep that in mind